# Spring Batch - Configure Tasklet in Step having reader and writer?

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch boot example. In this example, I am looking to convert XML based application into annotation based application. However I am struggling to configure using @Bean in Step to create exact configuration.

```xml
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="paymentDataReader" writer="paymentDataWriter" commit-interval="100000">
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="paymentingStepExecutionListener" />
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="sendpaymentingBatchFiles" />
    </batch:step>
```

JobConfiguration.java

```java
    @Configuration
    public class JobConfiguration {
        @Autowired
        private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public PaymentContextTasklet paymentContextTasklet() {
            return new PaymentContextTasklet();
        }

        // Either execute for "Payment" or "Order"
        @Bean
        public ContextDecider contextDecider() {
            return new ContextDecider();
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcPagingItemReader<Payment> pagingItemReader(){
            JdbcPagingItemReader<Payment> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
            reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
            reader.setFetchSize(10);
            reader.setRowMapper(new PaymentRowMapper());

            MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
            queryProvider.setSelectClause("select paymentId, amount, customerId, paymentDate");
            queryProvider.setFromClause("from payment");

            reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
            return reader;
        }

        @Bean
        public ItemWriter<Payment> paymentItemWriter(){
            return items -> {
                for(Payment c : items) {
                    System.out.println(c.toString());
                }
            };
        }

        @Bean
        public PaymentStepExecutionListener paymentStepExecutionListener() {
            return new PaymentStepExecutionListener();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step step1() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .<Payment, Payment>chunk(10)
                    .reader(pagingItemReader())
                    .writer(paymentItemWriter())
                    .tasklet(paymentStepExecutionListener())
                    .rea
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public PaymentDataTasklet paymentDataTasklet() {
            return new PaymentDataTasklet();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step paymentContextStep() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("paymentContextStep")
                    .tasklet(paymentContextTasklet())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step paymentDataStep() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("paymentDataStep")
                    .tasklet(paymentDataTasklet())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step endStep() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("endStep")
                    .tasklet(null)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Job paymentDataBatchJob() {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("paymentDataBatchJob")
                    .start(paymentContextStep())
                    .next(contextDecider())
                        .on("Payment").to(paymentDataStep()).on("COMPLETED").to(endStep)
                    .from(contextDecider())
                        .on("Order").to(endStep()).end()
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mahmoud Ben Hassine. I realize that I should be using `paymentStepExecutionListener` in `listener` and not in `Tasklet`.

One more thing is `StepExecutionListener` only works within a bean defined in the `scope="step".` so I should be using

// You can access the stepExecutionContext only within a bean defined in the //scope="step".

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public PaymentStepExecutionListener paymentStepExecutionListener() {
    return new PaymentStepExecutionListener();
}
```

Now things working very fine.

Answer (score 0):

> However I am struggling to configure using @Bean in Step to create exact configuration.

The equivalent of your XML snippet in Java config would be something like:

```
   @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Payment, Payment>chunk(100000)
                .reader(paymentDataReader())
                .writer(paymentDataWriter())
                .listener(paymentingStepExecutionListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job paymentDataBatchJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("paymentDataBatchJob")
                .start(step1())
                .next(sendpaymentingBatchFiles())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: `sendpaymentingBatchFiles` is a part of the Step1,  could you please correct `paymentDataBatchJob` ?

Comment: No, in your XML: `<batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="sendpaymentingBatchFiles" />` so `sendpaymentingBatchFiles` is another step. This means when step1 finishes with exit status COMPLETED, the flow should continue to `sendpaymentingBatchFiles`. The equivalent in Java config is shown in the answer.

Comment: Ah Ok, so XML snippet Step is active as a Master - having two task, but in read both are different, but dependent on each other ? How Can I used on="COMPLETED" to="sendBillingBatchFiles"  ? Is this correct ?

`return jobBuilderFactory.get("paymentDataBatchJob")
    .start(paymentContextStep())
    .next(contextDecider())
     .on("Payment").to(paymentDataStep()).on("COMPLETED").to(step1()).next(sendPaymentBatchFiles())
    .from(contextDecider())
     .on("Order").to(endStep()).end()
    .build();`